# I don't know how to implement a logic in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, architecture

I added a `status` to my Task Entity, and I will know which can be the best way to put the logic to set this `status` before send it to the front. Should be in the `TaskController`. Should be on the Services ? I don't think so but I'm not sure. I put a sample of the logic I want to add to set the status :

```
private function loadStatus(Task $task): string
    {
        $object = new \stdClass();

        $object->isDone = $task->isTaskDone();
        $object->isLate = date("Y-m-d") > $task->getDateStart();
        $object->isScheduled = date("Y-m-d") < $task->getDateStart() && !$task->isTaskDone();


        if ($object->isDone) {
                return 'task is done';
        }

        if ($object->isLate) {
            return 'task is late';
        }

        if ($object->isScheduled) {
            return 'task is scheduled'
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh yes thanks I forgot the negation .
In the Entity itself ok thank you very much I will do that

Comment: And do you think `$object` should be a class in other file and not a `stdClass` ?

Comment: Ok But it's because I have more logic but yes I can put directly all this things in the if yes

Comment: Oh yes much better , thank you for the interesting read too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the logic in the entity itself, as additional methods; after all it's entity behavior, following [doctrine's best practices](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/25).

```
class Task 
{
    const STATE_DONE = 'done';
    // Other constants ommited

    public function isScheduled()
    {
        return date("Y-m-d") < $this->getDateStart() && !$this->isTaskDone();
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        if ($this->isTaskDone()) {
                return self::STATE_DONE;
        }
        // Rest ommited 
    }
}
```

Then you can use them in the templates to generate the descriptions, where you have access to the translator.

```
{{ task.status | trans }}
```

Comment: Exactly What I wanted to know , thank you very much